# How to programmatically create UIView with landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, orientation, transform

I have an iPad application with fixed landscape orientation. Everything works OK until the moment when I programmatically create UIView and add it to my root UIViewController's view - it's orientation is always set to portrait while all other content is displayed in landscape mode. This UIView is a modal view showing some custom form for user.

```
AlertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
AlertView.opaque = NO;
AlertView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
AlertView.alpha = 0.7;

<...> // some other configuration code

[window addSubview:AlertView];
```

So the question is: how can I initiate UIView with landscape orientation? All I can think of is using transform like:

```
modalView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 180 * M_PI ) / 360 );
```

Though it's not too elegant way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your AlertView gets displayed in portrait orientation while the rest of your app gets displayed in landscape is because you are adding the AlertView as a subview of your window rather than adding it as a subview of a view controller's view.  This places it outside of the view hierarchy that gets transformed automatically through autorotation.

The app's window object coordinates autorotation by finding its topmost subview that has a corresponding view controller.  Upon device rotation, the window calls `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` on this view controller and transforms its view as appropriate.  If you want your view to autorotate, it must be a part of this view's hierarchy.

So instead of `[window addSubview:AlertView];`, do something like `[self.view addSubview:AlertView];`.

Answer (score 0):

To make UIViews in landscape orientation, and provided you want your root view controller to always be in portrait mode, you have 2 options:

1. Do it the way you are doing it by rotating the UIView using a transform
2. Change the way you are doing it to allow
   your root view controller to rotate (easiest). The view controller will then handle the rotations of your UIViews for you

Comment: Hmm... I asked completely other question. I have no problems with setting RootViewController to landscape mode only, the problem is that UIViews created programmatically are in portrait mode only.

Comment: Ummm, I answered that question... Edited to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting an autoresizing mask.
When the ViewController rotates, your AlertView's bounds would change, too.

```
yourView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```